# Website Product Specification Narrow Down URL List

Tags: c#, f#, set

I am looking for a simpler or elegant solution in object oriented (C#) or functional (F#) programming language to solve the following problem.

Given many thousands of products with specifications on an eCommerce website, consider the permutations of specification narrow down.  Specifically, what is the smallest set of specifications that yield different sets of products that a customer may be interested.

Users are given the opportunity to shop by any specification. For example take bolts.  They have Drill Size, Finish (Plain, Zinc, etc.), Head Type, Head Height, Grade, Length, Package Quantity, etc.

In an average product category, say there is 1000 products and 10 specifications.  If each specification can be added to the URL, what are the possible pages.  However, I am not just interested in all the permutations.  Consider the following points:
- by selecting one specification, many others are also selected because they are shared by the remaining set of products, and can be shown to the website user as also shared among the listed products
- once there is only one product listed all remaining specifications are naturally selected
- by placing the specification in a strict order (such as alphabetical) on the URL, this reduces unnecessary repetition

First, the problem was tackled with recursive SQL, (CTE syntax) and this became unwieldy, yielding millions of combinations per category before being able to start clearing out duplications.

Now, I am researching C# that takes on category at a time.
1) specifications types are ordered alphabetically
2) all products sets are compared with all others with the following code so as auto-select/auto-define additional specifications:

```
public bool DefinesThisValue(CategoryValue value)
{
    if (this.ProductIds.Count > value.ProductIds.Count) return false;

    var intersect = this.ProductIds.Intersect(value.ProductIds);
    return intersect.Count() == this.ProductIds.Count;
}
```

2) next it attempts to traverse all selection sequences, respecting the above, after each selection the an addition path node is addition to a collection and path objects of copy/split if there are multiple additional selectable specifications

My current solution is requiring much debugging and has become overly complex.  Perhaps someone familiar with set theory and F# could propose something awesome.  Thanks for your consideration.

In repsonse to Daniel, here is a SQL layout of data.

DATA STRUCTURES:
TABLES:

```
    CREATE TABLE Category
(
    Id int identity not null,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Spec
(
    Id int identity not null,
    CategoryId int not null REFERENCES Category(Id),
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE SpecValue
(
    Id int identity not null,
    SpecId int not null REFERENCES Spec(Id),
    Value varchar(200) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Product
(
    Id int identity not null,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE SpecValueProduct
(
    Id int identity not null,
    SpecValueId int not null REFERENCES SpecValue(Id),
    ProductId int not null REFERENCES Product(Id),
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id)
)
```

A simple example might include the following example data:

```
Product 1: Coffee Maker A, Color: Black, Cups: 2
Product 2: Coffee Maker B, Color: Black, Cups: 4
Product 3: Coffee Maker C, Color: Grey, Cups: 4
```

In this example, then if Color: Grey is selected, then Cups: 4 is also defined.  But, if Color: Black is selected, then user has option to select Cup: 2 or Cups: 4.

A url might look like: 'site.com\coffee-makers?Color=Black&Cups=4

Comment: You're asking for a lot. Can you show the data structures you're dealing with?

Comment: Tried to put response for data structures in comment, not enough room...editing original post.

Comment: Add that to your question and delete the comment. It will be more readable and will help others offer you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's start simple. The first thing you need to do, I presume, is show the list of available specs and their values. Easy enough...

```
select s.Name, v.Id, v.Value 
from SpecValue v 
  inner join Spec s on s.Id = v.SpecId
where s.CategoryId = @CategoryId
```

If you want, you can also join it to `SpecValueProduct` to limit the specs/values to those currently in use.

Next, when spec values are selected, you'll need to run a similar query, but limiting it to relevant values, i.e., those applied to a product where the selected spec/values are present.

Given the parameter:

```
declare @SelectedSpecValue table (SpecValueId int)
```

You might do something like

```
select distinct s.Name, v.Id, v.Value, 
  cast(case when n.SpecValueId is null then 0 else 1 end as bit) as IsSelected
from SpecValue v 
  inner join Spec s on s.Id = v.SpecId
  inner join SpecValueProduct p on p.SpecValueId = v.Id
  inner join
  (
    select distinct y.ProductId
    from SpecValueProduct y
      inner join @SelectedSpecValue z on z.SpecValueId = y.SpecValueId

  ) x on x.ProductId = p.ProductId
  left join @SelectedSpecValue n on n.SpecValueId = v.Id
where s.CategoryId = @CategoryId
```

If I've written that correctly it should constrain the available spec values by those already selected. If not, it might do something entirely different. :-)

Am I oversimplifying this? Does it answer your question?

Comment: That looks good for giving the selected values once selected.  However, I am trying to solve for the set of inserts for @SelectedSpecValue in your code.  In other words, what is the smallest set of valid and different sets of specification values (URL's) that a shopping could go to in their navigation.

Comment: @SelectedSpecValue is just the list of values thus far selected. The values available for selection is the first query in my answer--a simple `SELECT`.

Comment: In my example of the coffee maker, when Color: Grey is selected, then Cups: 2 would no longer be a valid selection.  Your select would include this example.

Comment: That would be the second query. The first query is the initial population. The second query would be executed after any (and every) value is selected.

Comment: Not sure how to explain what I am going for.  The second query only returns it given a set of selects.  However, given a category with 10 specifications, there are 10 factorial set of selectable-combinations... which a million already... and there can be more than 10 specifications in a category of products.  Of these sets however, not nearly all will result in unique product results because of the considerations listed in my original post.  I know I am asking a lot, thanks for any input.